# how to add `intellij gradle plugin` to my custom plugin dependency

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I create a intellij plugin using recommended gradle.

I want to use gradle `projectResolve` in my plugin then I extends my class from `org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolverExtension` but it's not exist. I add bellow code to my gradle :

```
intellij {
    plugins = ['org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle']
}
```

but I receive this error:

```
Cannot find builtin plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle for IDE:
```

I add bellow library it's work but is too old.

```
    implementation 'com.github.adedayo.intellij.sdk:gradle:142.1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gradle plugin is bundled plugin and can add like

```
intellij {
    plugins = ['gradle']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
}
```